# How to add image to banner and have its position adjust to changing screen width

Tags: html, css

I am trying to add a photo to the banner and have it sit right above my logo on my webpage. I would like the photo to stay in the same position (over the logo) regardless of screen size, right now it stays in the same position within the banner. How do i fix this?

My current code looks like this

```css
div#banner {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  background-color: #00AD83;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100px;
}
div#banner-content {
  position: static;
  margin-left: 25%;
  padding: 0px;
  z-index: 1;
}
div#main-content {
  padding-top: 70px;
}
```

```html
<div id="banner">
  <div id="banner-content">
    <img src="/img/Banner-Words.jpg" alt="URGENT APPEAL" style="width:349px;height:100px;">
  </div>
```

Comment: I didn't understand your question

Comment: How do I add an image on my webpage (it happens to be in a banner at the top of my page) and have it stay in the same position regardless of the window size? When my window is at full resolution it is in the perfect position but when it shrinks at all it moves to the wrong position. Hope this helps make it more clear? My apologies on that!

Comment: We need to see html and CSS for that logo too, to know how it is positioned.

Comment: The logo is the image ?

Comment: I Just want the Banner Content image to stay in the same place on the page regardless of the screen size or window size

Answer (score 0):

Give to your logo a fixed margin in stead of a percentage.

```
div#banner-content { 
position: static;
margin-left: 30px; 
padding: 0px; 
z-index: 1;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

background-image="/img/Banner-Words.jpg" ?